# I want to get every resources wise billing for my Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I want to get every resources wise billing for my Azure portal account, after having a discussion with their support team they tell me to download that xls or invoice pdf, but it's not contain resource name and proper value for that.

Comment: I think cloudyn is not available for Pay-as-you-go subscription .

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a source why you think that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Comment: +1 for me. Question describes the situation exactly.  In the Azure portal, I see 90 Resources, VMs and data bases.  In the separate monthly invoice CSV file, it shows costs, but does not show the names of the Resources of the VMs that are assiciated.  It gives "ResourceGUID", which does not trace back to Resources.  I understand if that's off topic here, but it is a reasonable question if you've been assigned to do accounting (as I have, in same situation as OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Azure Cost Management (Cloudyn)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cost-management/

Cloudyn is a free-to-use service for Azure subscriptions, which help you to track costs of individual services and workloads. It also enables you to create custom dashboards and reports based on which services you want to track.

You can start using Cloudyn by logging in to Azure portal, and choosing "Cost Management + Billing" from the left hand blade, and clicking Cost Management.

Comment: seems useful...Thank you!